# VBA how to determine which application is being used

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a VBA function I use in MS Access and MS Excel. When used in MS Excel I use Application.Volatile but when it is placed or used in MS Access it will not compile. Is there a way to make this line interchangeable without having to delete it when placed in MS Access?

Thank you,
Fred

Comment: By the way, in my Ms Access applications I use late binding for any MS Excel procedures because of the mixed environment I am working in.  Mix in the since of MS Officer 2007 and MS Office 2010.  Soon to have MS Office 2013 as well.

Comment: You could use [conditional compilation](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/setting-up-a-debug-environment-for-vba/), but you would still have to modify the constant value.

Comment: That's is amazing. I had no clue. On the new tricks I am learning today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask for the name of the application:

```
If Application.Name = "Microsoft Access" then
   'Do Nothing ......Or whatever you need to do.

ElseIf Application.Name = "Microsoft Excel" then
    Application.Run "Application.Volatile"
End If
```

Comment: This is a great idea I did not know about but the application.run "Volatile" ends the function before executing the complete function.

Comment: Hi @FredWilson.  I Just corrected the code; it is necessary to fully specify the method name;  "Application.Volatile" not just "Volatile".

Comment: Thank you CaBieberach. I will work with that and see if it will get me by.

Answer (score 1):

From Help.

Visual Basic for Applications Reference

**CallByName Function**

Executes a method of an object, or sets or returns a property of an object.

Syntax

```
CallByName(object, procname, calltype,[args()])
```

The CallByName function syntax has these named arguments:

```
Part Description 
object Required; Variant (Object). The name of the object on which the function will be executed. 
procname Required; Variant (String). A string expression containing the name of a property or method of the object. 
calltype Required; Constant. A constant of type vbCallType representing the type of procedure being called. 
args() Optional: Variant (Array).
```

**Remarks**

The CallByName function is used to get or set a property, or invoke a method at run time using a string name.

In the following example, the first line uses CallByName to set the MousePointer property of a text box, the second line gets the value of the MousePointer property, and the third line invokes the Move method to move the text box:

```
CallByName Text1, "MousePointer", vbLet, vbCrosshair
Result = CallByName (Text1, "MousePointer", vbGet)
CallByName Text1, "Move", vbMethod, 100, 100
```

---

Send feedback to MSDN.Look here for MSDN Online resources.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the point here. I will have to look up CallByName.

Comment: I believe what @Serenity means is: `If Application.Name = "Microsoft Excel" Then CallByName Application, "Volatile", VbMethod, True`

Comment: Without you guys how does one figure this stuff out? ;-)